# Show hidden elements when the inside checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Problem:**

I'm on prestashop and i need to customize a filter menu. I have a **left column** that contains the filters of all category's. So, if you click on a element of the list, all products of that category will be showed.

[Products page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH2vl.png)

There are many category: is for that, i reduce the list of category's with a little button that if it's clicked, all category will be explosed.

['Mostra di piu' is the button for blow up all category - exemple 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUw4D.png)

[Exemple 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VIV4.png)

But if you check some elements in the list of category of filter, the page will refresh and the menu automatically will resize.

**What i tried?**

For provide that, i choise to use the cookie (it will expire after 1.30 min) and let open the filter menu also when the page refresh. If the cookie ***menu_sinistra*** is set on '*open*', the menu will be stay explosed. Here the code:

```
    $('#search_filters ul.collapse').on('click','.more_filter', function(){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (90 * 1000));
  if( $(this).hasClass('less') ){    
    $(this).text('{l s='Show More' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}').removeClass('less'); 
  }else{
    $(this).text('{l s='Show Less' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}').addClass('less'); 
  }
  $(this).siblings('li.toggleable').slideToggle();
  $.cookie("menu_sinistra", "open",{ expires: date });
  return false;
});

if($.cookie("menu_sinistra") == 'open') {
    $('#search_filters ul.collapse li.toggleable').show();   
    $('#search_filters ul.collapse .more_filter').text('{l s='Show Less' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}').addClass('less');
}
```

And this is HTML code:

```
<section class="facet clearfix">
<p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Categorie</p>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_7026" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
  <p class="h6 facet-title">Categorie</p>
  <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
    <i class="material-icons add"></i>
    <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
  </span>
</div>

          
    <ul id="facet_7026" class="collapse in">
                      
        <li>
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_0">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_0" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Accessori per Climatizzatori
                                      <span class="magnitude">(39)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li>
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_1">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_1" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Attrezzatura per montaggio
                                      <span class="magnitude">(82)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li>
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_2">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_2" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="c" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Aermec
                                      <span class="magnitude">(16)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li>
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_3">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_3" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href=" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Clivet
                                      <span class="magnitude">(40)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li>
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_4">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_4" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Daikin
                                      <span class="magnitude">(31)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_5">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_5" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Haier
                                      <span class="magnitude">(54)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_6">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_6" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Hisense
                                      <span class="magnitude">(17)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_7">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_7" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori LG
                                      <span class="magnitude">(22)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label active " for="facet_input_7026_8">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_8" data-search-url="" type="checkbox" checked="">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Mitsubishi
                                      <span class="magnitude">(29)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_9">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_9" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Olimpia Splendid
                                      <span class="magnitude">(4)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_10">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_10" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Panasonic
                                      <span class="magnitude">(20)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_11">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_11" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Portatili
                                      <span class="magnitude">(4)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_12">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_12" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Samsung
                                      <span class="magnitude">(33)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                      
        <li style="display: list-item;" class="toggleable">
          <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_7026_13">
                                  <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input id="facet_input_7026_13" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                          <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                      </span>
            
            <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
              Climatizzatori Toshiba
                                      <span class="magnitude">(20)</span>
                                  </a>
          </label>
        </li>
                  <li class="more_filter less">Mostra meno</li></ul>
  

      </section>
      <section class="facet clearfix">
        <p class="h6 facet-title hidden-sm-down">Marca</p>
                                                                                                                                    
        <div class="title hidden-md-up" data-target="#facet_58821" data-toggle="collapse">
          <p class="h6 facet-title">Marca</p>
          <span class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons">
            <i class="material-icons add"></i>
            <i class="material-icons remove"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

                  
            <ul id="facet_58821" class="collapse">
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_0">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_0" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Arnocanali
                                              <span class="magnitude">(2)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_1">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_1" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Elettronew
                                              <span class="magnitude">(4)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_2">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_2" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Fischer
                                              <span class="magnitude">(2)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_3">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_3" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href=" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Konelco GBS
                                              <span class="magnitude">(1)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li>
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_4">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_4" data-search-url="q=Categorie-Climatizzatori+Mitsubishi/Marca-Mitsubishi" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="q=Categorie-Climatizzatori+Mitsubishi/Marca-Mitsubishi" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Mitsubishi
                                              <span class="magnitude">(18)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                              
                <li style="display: none;" class="toggleable">
                  <label class="facet-label" for="facet_input_58821_5">
                                          <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input id="facet_input_58821_5" data-search-url="" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="ps-shown-by-js"><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked"></i></span>
                                              </span>
                    
                    <a href="" class="_gray-darker search-link js-search-link" rel="nofollow">
                      Tecnogas
                                              <span class="magnitude">(2)</span>
                                          </a>
                  </label>
                </li>
                          <li class="more_filter">Mostra di più</li></ul>
          

              </section>
```

But another problem is born: when i click on "mostra di piu" (the class is '***more_filter***'), all the menu of the other div with same class (**toggleable**) will explose.

**What i need?**

I need that just the toggleable of the div where the elements are checked must be explosed. How can i do that?